# Tests do not work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

i try add a new tests in my class test, but the new method just don't work. i use xUnit and MOQ.

[image]

```
[Theory]
[Trait("Category", "Selecao")]
public void teste()
{
    Assert.Empty("");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `[Theory]` with `[Fact]`

A `[Theory]` must have testdata, like this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(3)]
[InlineData(5)]
[InlineData(6)]
public void MyFirstTheory(int value)
{
    Assert.True(IsOdd(value));
}
```

For `[Fact]`, this is not needed, example:

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    Assert.Empty("");
}
```

More info at: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop#write-first-theory